# How to loop through every windows service in batch

Tags: batch-file, service, windows-10

I am trying to create a batch script that changes services' startup types based on their service names. But something is not working in my loop, and I don't know why it is not working :( Please help :)

I've already tried taking the command I'm using as what I'm searching through and ran it through cmd. It works fine. However, when I insert it into my loop, it refuses to function. I am fairly new to batch, and I don't understand...

This is what I have right now:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
pause

set "autosvc=;BrokerInfrastructure;BFE;"&REM list of services set to auto
set "delayedautosvc=;BITS;CDPSvc;"&REM list of services set to delayed-auto
set "delayedautosvc=;AxInstSV;AJRouter;"&REM list of services set to manual

for /f "tokens=1 delims=," %%i in ('sc query type= service state= all ') do (
    set tmpry=0
    if "!autosvc:;%%~i;=!" equ "!autosvc!" ( set /a tmpry=1 
    ) else ( if "!delayedautosvc:;%%~i;=!" equ "!delayedautosvc!" ( set /a tmpry=2
    ) else ( if "!demandsvc:;%%~i;=!" equ "!demandsvc!" ( set /a tmpry=3 )
    ) )
    if !tmpry! equ 1 ( echo AUTOMATIC - %%~i )
    if !tmpry! equ 2 ( echo DELAYEDAUTOMATIC - %%~i )
    if !tmpry! equ 3 ( echo MANUAL - %%~i )
    if !tmpry! lss 1 ( echo DISABLE - %%~i )
)
pause
```

Unfortunately this is the output:

```
Configuring service settings...
AUTOMATIC - ERROR:  Invalid Option
AUTOMATIC - DESCRIPTION:
AUTOMATIC -         SC is a command line program used for communicating with the
AUTOMATIC -         Service Control Manager and services.
AUTOMATIC - USAGE:
AUTOMATIC -         sc <server> [command] [service name] <option1> <option2>...
AUTOMATIC -         The option <server> has the form "\\ServerName"
AUTOMATIC -         Further help on commands can be obtained by typing: "sc [command]"
AUTOMATIC -         Commands:
AUTOMATIC -           query-----------Queries the status for a service
AUTOMATIC -                           enumerates the status for types of services.
AUTOMATIC -           queryex---------Queries the extended status for a service
AUTOMATIC -                           enumerates the status for types of services.
AUTOMATIC -           start-----------Starts a service.
AUTOMATIC -           pause-----------Sends a PAUSE control request to a service.
AUTOMATIC -           interrogate-----Sends an INTERROGATE control request to a service.
AUTOMATIC -           continue--------Sends a CONTINUE control request to a service.
AUTOMATIC -           stop------------Sends a STOP request to a service.
AUTOMATIC -           config----------Changes the configuration of a service (persistent).
AUTOMATIC -           description-----Changes the description of a service.
AUTOMATIC -           failure---------Changes the actions taken by a service upon failure.
AUTOMATIC -           failureflag-----Changes the failure actions flag of a service.
AUTOMATIC -           sidtype---------Changes the service SID type of a service.
AUTOMATIC -           privs-----------Changes the required privileges of a service.
AUTOMATIC -           managedaccount--Changes the service to mark the service account
AUTOMATIC -                           password as managed by LSA.
AUTOMATIC -           qc--------------Queries the configuration information for a service.
AUTOMATIC -           qdescription----Queries the description for a service.
AUTOMATIC -           qfailure--------Queries the actions taken by a service upon failure.
AUTOMATIC -           qfailureflag----Queries the failure actions flag of a service.
AUTOMATIC -           qsidtype--------Queries the service SID type of a service.
AUTOMATIC -           qprivs----------Queries the required privileges of a service.
AUTOMATIC -           qtriggerinfo----Queries the trigger parameters of a service.
AUTOMATIC -           qpreferrednode--Queries the preferred NUMA node of a service.
AUTOMATIC -           qmanagedaccount-Queries whether a services uses an account with a
AUTOMATIC -                           password managed by LSA.
AUTOMATIC -           qprotection-----Queries the process protection level of a service.
AUTOMATIC -           quserservice----Queries for a local instance of a user service template.
AUTOMATIC -           delete----------Deletes a service (from the registry).
AUTOMATIC -           create----------Creates a service. (adds it to the registry).
AUTOMATIC -           control---------Sends a control to a service.
AUTOMATIC -           sdshow----------Displays a service's security descriptor.
AUTOMATIC -           sdset-----------Sets a service's security descriptor.
AUTOMATIC -           showsid---------Displays the service SID string corresponding to an arbitrary name.
AUTOMATIC -           triggerinfo-----Configures the trigger parameters of a service.
AUTOMATIC -           preferrednode---Sets the preferred NUMA node of a service.
AUTOMATIC -           GetDisplayName--Gets the DisplayName for a service.
AUTOMATIC -           GetKeyName------Gets the ServiceKeyName for a service.
AUTOMATIC -           EnumDepend------Enumerates Service Dependencies.
AUTOMATIC -         The following commands don't require a service name:
AUTOMATIC -         sc <server> <command> <option>
AUTOMATIC -           boot------------(ok | bad) Indicates whether the last boot should
AUTOMATIC -                           be saved as the last-known-good boot configuration
AUTOMATIC -           Lock------------Locks the Service Database
AUTOMATIC -           QueryLock-------Queries the LockStatus for the SCManager Database
AUTOMATIC - EXAMPLE:
AUTOMATIC -         sc start MyService
AUTOMATIC - QUERY and QUERYEX OPTIONS:
AUTOMATIC -         If the query command is followed by a service name
AUTOMATIC -         for that service is returned.  Further options do not apply in
AUTOMATIC -         this case.  If the query command is followed by nothing or one of
AUTOMATIC -         the options listed below
AUTOMATIC -     type=    Type of services to enumerate (driver
AUTOMATIC -              (default = service)
AUTOMATIC -     state=   State of services to enumerate (inactive
AUTOMATIC -              (default = active)
AUTOMATIC -     bufsize= The size (in bytes) of the enumeration buffer
AUTOMATIC -              (default = 4096)
AUTOMATIC -     ri=      The resume index number at which to begin the enumeration
AUTOMATIC -              (default = 0)
AUTOMATIC -     group=   Service group to enumerate
AUTOMATIC -              (default = all groups)
AUTOMATIC - SYNTAX EXAMPLES
AUTOMATIC - sc query                - Enumerates status for active services & drivers
AUTOMATIC - sc query eventlog       - Displays status for the eventlog service
AUTOMATIC - sc queryex eventlog     - Displays extended status for the eventlog service
AUTOMATIC - sc query type= driver   - Enumerates only active drivers
AUTOMATIC - sc query type= service  - Enumerates only Win32 services
AUTOMATIC - sc query state= all     - Enumerates all services & drivers
AUTOMATIC - sc query bufsize= 50    - Enumerates with a 50 byte buffer
AUTOMATIC - sc query ri= 14         - Enumerates with resume index = 14
AUTOMATIC - sc queryex group= ""    - Enumerates active services not in a group
AUTOMATIC - sc query type= interact - Enumerates all interactive services
AUTOMATIC - sc query type= driver group= NDIS     - Enumerates all NDIS drivers
```

Comment: You need to escape equal signs in the `sc` command line, like this: `sc query type^= service state^= all`. Then you'll realize that your parsing is quite wrong.

Comment: You have 6 services so you need 6 lines.

Comment: I think that you're over complicating the task. There is no need to find out what the start type of each service is, just configure them, if they're already set to the same start mode, nothing should change.

Comment: Yeah, I've given up using sc and resorted to wmic, and now more of it works, but it still has "AUTOMATIC" at the front each time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've actually found a solution to my own problem after finding various simple mistakes in my program. 
My solution, in case anyone is curious (probably not):

```
@echo off
title Services Script
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
pause

set "autosvc=;BrokerInfrastructure;BFE;EventSystem;CDPUserSvc_;DiagTrack;CoreMessagingRegistrar;CryptSvc;DusmSvc;DcomLaunch;Dhcp;DPS;TrkWks;Dnscache;gpsvc;LSM;NlaSvc;nsi;Power;Spooler;PcaSvc;RpcSs;RpcEptMapper;SamSs;LanmanServer;ShellHWDetection;SysMain;SENS;SystemEventsBroker;Schedule;Themes;UserManager;ProfSvc;AudioSrv;AudioEndpointBuilder;Wcmsvc;WinDefend;MpsSvc;SecurityHealthService;EventLog;FontCache;Winmgmt;WpnService;WpnUserService_;LanmanWorkstation;MBAMService;^!SASCORE;FileZilla Server;FileZilla;VMware;VMTools;"
set "delayedautosvc=;BITS;CDPSvc;DoSvc;wscsvc;sppsvc;OneSyncSvc_;WSearch;SgrmBroker;MMCSS"
set "demandsvc=;AxInstSV;AJRouter;AppReadiness;AppIDSvc;Appinfo;AppMgmt;AppXSVC;AssignedAccessManagerSvc;BDESVC;wbengine;BTAGService;bthserv;BluetoothUserService_;camsvc;CaptureService_;CertPropSvc;ClipSVC;KeyIso;COMSysApp;Browser;PimIndexMaintenanceSvc_;VaultSvc;DsSvc;DeviceAssociationService;DeviceInstall;DmEnrollmentSvc;DsmSVC;DevicePickerUserSvc_;DevicesFlowUserSvc_;DevQueryBroker;diagsvc;WdiServiceHost;WdiSystemHost;MSDTC;embeddedmode;EFS;EntAppSvc;EapHost;fhsvc;fdPHost;FDResPub;BcastDVRUserService_;GraphicsPerfSvc;hidserv;IKEEXT;UI0Detect;IpxlatCfgSvc;PolicyAgent;KtmRm;lltdsvc;wlpasvc;MessagingService_;diagnosticshub.standardcollector.service;NgcSvc;NgcCtnrSvc;swprv;smphost;InstallService;NcdAutoSetup;NcbService;Netman;NcaSVC;netprofm;NetSetupSvc;ssh-agent;defragsvc;PNRPsvc;p2psvc;p2pimsvc;PerfHost;pla;PlugPlay;PNRPAutoReg;WPDBusEnum;PrintNotify;PrintWorkflowUserSvc_;wercplsupport;QWAVE;RmSvc;seclogon;SstpSvc;SharedRealitySvc;svsvc;SSDPSRV;StateRepository;WiaRpc;StorSvc;TieringEngineService;lmhosts;TapiSrv;TimeBroker;UsoSvc;upnphost;UserDataSvc_;UnistoreSvc_;vds;VSS;WalletService;WarpJITSvc;TokenBroker;WebClient;SDRSVC;wcncsvc;Sense;WdNisSvc;WEPHOSTSVC;WerSvc;Wecsvc;StiSvc;msiserver;LicenseManager;TrustedInstaller;spectrum;PushToInstall;W32Time;wuauserv;WaaSMedicSvc;WinHttpAutoProxySvc;dot3svc;WlanSvc;wmiApSrv;XboxGipSvc;xbgm;BthAvctpSvc;MozillaMaintenance;"

echo CONFIGURING SERVICE SETTINGS...

for /f "skip=1 tokens=1 delims=, " %%i in ('wmic service get name') do ( 
    set tmpry=0
    if "!autosvc:;%%~i;=!" neq "!autosvc!" ( set /a tmpry=2 )
    if "!delayedautosvc:;%%~i;=!" neq "!delayedautosvc!" ( set /a tmpry=4 ) 
    if "!demandsvc:;%%~i;=!" neq "!demandsvc!" ( set /a tmpry=6 )

    if !tmpry! equ 2 ( echo AUTOMATIC - %%~i )
    if !tmpry! equ 4 ( echo DELAYEDAUTOMATIC - %%~i )
    if !tmpry! equ 6 ( echo MANUAL - %%~i )
    if !tmpry! lss 1 ( echo DISABLE - %%~i )
)

echo ARE YOU SURE YOU WANT THESE SETTINGS?
pause

echo Automatic Start: > "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\ServiceConfigurations.txt"
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1 delims=, " %%i in ('wmic service get name') do ( 
    set tmpry=0
    if "!autosvc:;%%~i;=!" neq "!autosvc!" ( set /a tmpry=2 )
    if "!delayedautosvc:;%%~i;=!" neq "!delayedautosvc!" ( set /a tmpry=4 ) 
    if "!demandsvc:;%%~i;=!" neq "!demandsvc!" ( set /a tmpry=6 )

    if !tmpry! equ 2 ( 
        sc \\%COMPUTERNAME% config %%~i start= auto )
    if !tmpry! equ 4 ( 
        sc \\%COMPUTERNAME% config %%~i start= delayed-auto )
    if !tmpry! equ 6 ( 
        sc \\%COMPUTERNAME% config %%~i start= demand )
    if !tmpry! lss 1 ( 
        sc \\%COMPUTERNAME% config %%~i start= disabled
        sc \\%COMPUTERNAME% stop %%~i )
)

echo Service settings configured.
pause
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example along the lines of my comment, which would simply set the start type, regardless of its current mode. There's no need for logging the current values and comparing them first, just make the configuration changes required:

```bat
@For %%A In (BrokerInfrastructure,BFE)Do @SC config %%A start= auto
@For %%A In (BITS,CDPSvc)Do @SC config %%A start= delayed-auto
@For %%A In (AxInstSV,AJRouter)Do @SC config %%A start= demand
```

You would also need to run this `.cmd` script as Administrator

**[Edit /]**

This is an extension of the code above and my commented use of WMIC to retrieve the non disabled services. I have included it in order to follow the methodology of only disabling those services which are not already disabled, and which do not exist in your configuration listings.

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion

(   For %%A In (BrokerInfrastructure,BFE
    )Do SC config %%A start= auto>CON 2>&1&Echo(\^<%%A\^>
    For %%A In (BITS,CDPSvc
    )Do SC config %%A start= delayed-auto>CON 2>&1&Echo(\^<%%A\^>
    For %%A In (AxInstSV,AJRouter
    )Do SC config %%A start= demand>CON 2>&1&Echo(\^<%%A\^>
)>"mylist.txt"

For /F "Skip=1Delims=" %%A In ('WMIC Service Where "StartMode!='Disabled'"^
 Get Name^|FindStr /IVG:"mylist.txt" 2^>Nul')Do For %%B In (%%A
 )Do SC config %%B start= disabled

Del "mylist.txt"
```

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, but what I meant in my question was that I need to set listed services' startup types to auto, delayed auto, or demand, but for the services not listed, I want to set them to disabled. That is why I tried to loop through all services and check each one's name. Thanks though!

Comment: Do you mean all services on the PC which aren't in your list? If so what is the target OS because the destination will hardly be one.

Comment: Yes that is what I mean. Target OS: Win 10, but some additional downloaded programs may have created services that are unwanted.

Comment: Well I absolutely do not agree that this is something you should be doing, but if you want to render your own PC unusable, that's your issue. As I indicated previously, there's no need to be listing things and making comparisions, the PC is already running and as you're only changing its start mode, modifying that will not take affect until your next restart. Perhaps you could begin the script with a [tag:wmic] command to disable everything at the outset: `@WMIC Service Where "StartMode!='Disabled'" Call ChangeStartMode Disabled` should theoretically do that, then run the **`3`** lines above.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I see what you mean, but the lists above are just a small sample of what I have in my list, so all necessary windows services are also in them. I wanted to avoid disabling them all before because that would risk disabling necessary processes and thus rendering my machine unusable.

Comment: The only way that should happen is if something causes the system to crash\reboot\logout whilst the script was part way through, _(but I'm sure that could happen during many scripted processes)_. And I'm sure that wouldn't matter as you will have made a backup of the system state or at least have a listing of all of their prior start modes before commencing.

Comment: I am currently working on the script on a virtual machine, just to be safe, but I, of course, want to minimize the risk of crashing my machine because I look to possibly use it on my actual machine in the future. And that is why I tried to only disable the services that aren't on my lists instead of disabling all the services then enabling the ones I need. I just need to be safe. :)

Comment: Changing the configuration data of a service for when or how it'd next start shouldn't be a likely contender for a system event of that type, despite the potential severity of your future actions.

Comment: Alright thanks! Turns out I found my problem in my initial code and was able to have it work without disabling all the services and reenabling them in the process. :)

Comment: You don't seem to understand my point, you're not disabling any services, you're configuring a setting to tell it what happens on the next start up. Nothing changes until that start up, so there is no issue changing the setting as many times as you need to before that time. Still, as long as you have something you're satisfied with, that's the main thing.

Comment: Yes I understood that. I understand that I might have been a bit too cautious in my approach, but it actually paid off, as my virtual machine did actually crash during runtime of the script while configuring. However, as I had used my original, safer approach in the script, my vm restarted properly and I was able to use it.

Comment: @returnfun, I have added an **[Edit /]** which should better cater for your methodology, please feel free to take a look and implement it as required.

Comment: @returnfun, why have you ignored my edit, or at least comment on it? Does it not perform the task you requested? Does it fail to work in some other way?

Comment: Ahh... sorry about my lack of response. I have been very busy with other things recently. As of your edited solution, I find it unnecessary to disable only the services that are already disabled, though that may improve efficiency. Thus, I have provided my own solution above, if you would like to see what I meant to do to start.

Comment: @returnfun, that's not what my code does, it disables only the services which are not in your lists and which were not already disabled. I thought I'd explained it well enough. _Please try it, if you change each instance of `SC` to `Echo(SC`, it should just print the commands, so that you can see exactly what would happen_.